# Google-maps:Displaying address in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

iam trying to implement infowindows with address displaying in it ..
below is my code

```
    $('#citiesdata').empty(); 

    var listFavourite = [];

    $(responce).find("favorite").each(function() {
      var name = $(this).find("name").text();
      var address = $(this).find("address").text(); 
      var phoneNo = $(this).find("phoneNo").text();
      var lattitude = $(this).find("lattitude").text();
      var longitude = $(this).find("longitude").text();

      var favouriteObject = new Object();
          favouriteObject.name = name;
              favouriteObject.address = address;
              favouriteObject.lattitude = lattitude;
              favouriteObject.longitude = longitude;
          listFavourite.push(favouriteObject);

      $('#citiesdata').append('<tr><td><b>'+name+'</b></td></tr>');
      $('#citiesdata').append('<tr><td>'+address+'</td></tr>');
      $('#citiesdata').append('<tr><td>'+phoneNo+'</td></tr>');



    });
    //call map service to load map with marker
    //method name(listFavourite);
  var content =   "<div id='tabs'>"+
                                "<form id='button'>"+
                                "<div>"+
                                "<input type='button' value='click me' onclick='alert(\"infoWindow\")'>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>";

         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
               streetViewControl: false
        });
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         //content: content
        });

       for (var n = 0 ; n <listFavourite.length ; n++)
           addMarker(listFavourite[n]);
       }


       function addMarker(data) {
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lattitude, data.longitude),
               map: map,
               title: data.address
           });
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
               infowindow.setContent(data.address);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           });

       };
```

here i am getting the data(addresses) from a arraylist..and i want to display that address in the infowindows..thankyou

Comment: changed the infowindow.setContent(content); to infowindow.setContent(data.address); but same addres is repeating for all markers...any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your markers in a separate function:

```
for (var n = 0 ; n <listFavourite.length ; n++)
    addMarker(listFavourite[n]);
}


function addMarker(data) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lattitude, data.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: data.address
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.setContent(data.address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

};
```

Comment: integrated your code but getting foolowing error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: You've integrated it wrongly. Edit your question to reflect your **complete** current code, including the contents of the listFavourite array

Comment: When you create the map object you need to specify center and zoom in the mapOptions. Both parameters are required, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Imagine that I am not going to spend all day on this one question. Update your code and describe what error you're getting on the javascript console. And what does 'itz' mean?

Comment: here is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/XipTahb6   in the console iam gettinh infowindow is not defined

Comment: solved..preiviously i created infowindow in wrong place...Thankyou Marcelo

Comment: You're welcome. For the next time, remember to post your complete script, from <script> to </script>. Then you'll get a good answer sooner. :-)

Comment: sure Marcelo..one simple query ..i geting the address in infowindow but i can see only when i doulbe click in infowindow..am i missing something creating infowindow

Comment: There is no event handler in your code that should cause what you describe. Anyway, try creating the infoWindow without parameters, ie: var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

Comment: i already created infowin without parameters..see my code here:http://pastebin.com/hx4BNDKG